# Brake calipers rubbing rim after changing pads

Tags: car, kia

Sounds like I'm dragging my exhaust down the road. I pinpointed the issue to my brake calipers rubbing my rim. Nothing's changed but brake pads. What should I do? Other than getting spacers...

Comment: Something is likely not re-installed properly.  The calipers should not be rubbing on the wheels.

Comment: Do your callipers only have pistons on one side?

Comment: Are your rims or callipers non-standard for the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! These are some excellent questions ... if you could help us understand, we can most likely help you.

Comment: Suddenly needing spacers is a sure sign you have reassembled it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If your vehicle has either non-standard wheels or non-standard brake callipers installed, it may have been relying on not having full thickness pads installed for the calliper not to touch the wheel rim.

If the calliper has a slider mechanism with pistons only on the one side of the calliper, as in the photo below, the calliper will be nearer the rim with thicker pads installed. As the pads wear, the calliper will move further from the wheel rim as it centres on the disc/rotor.

If this is what is happening, you could try to get thinner pads, sand the outer pad down a little, or return the vehicle to original fittings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that there are actually both pads in the caliper.
2. Check that the pads are lined with the braking side to the rotor and the steel backing plates are pointing outwards.
3. Check that the caliper bracket got installed correctly on the mounting